# Do I have to use "an" or "woran"?

Tags: interrogative

I'm learning German all by myself and I face here an inconsistency. I learnt I have to say

> "Woran was denkst du?"

[hier](https://www.allemandfacile.com/exercices/exercice-allemand-2/exercice-allemand-24731.php) but [there](https://youtu.be/58U2IvsjSrk?t=40s) she asks the question

> "An was denkst du?"

In the lesson (in french) they say it's not correct to use "an". So is it really the case or is it possible to use it (at least when speaking) as people in many different languages tend to speak their languge in a worse way except when they write?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ my concrete examples are in the links I gave you. I can't invent them.

Comment: There were only unfortunate forrmatting issues probably.

Comment: In the lesson of the first link, they say correct "Le verbe 'denken' se constuit avec la préposition 'an'", so the statement "On serait tenté de dire 'an was denkst du'." is indeed correct!

Comment: Quick but accurate rule: German questions only ever have **one** w-interrogative form, so "woran was" is guaranteed to be wrong.

Comment: "woran was" does not appear in the first linked page. It is not clear to me how you arrive at the conclusion that that is what you "have to say".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either say

> Woran denkst Du?

or

> An was denkst Du?

Both are fine.
There are different ways to say the same thing.

Comment: +1, but an eye-opening example would be: *An **wen** denkst du?* There's not even an alternative for using **an** there.

Comment: @Janka I've made the experience that one can easily confuse or overwhelm a learner with to much (extra) information. Since it's difficult online to watch their reaction, I try to follow the (KISS-principle)[ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle] and keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed *woran* is more elegant, but *an was* is not wrong. Wiktionary calls it [colloquial](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/was) (near the end).

Comment: I've also heard in colloquial speech: "Was denkst (du) an?" How "wrong" is this? Can you comment on this?

Comment: @Beta, that word order seems just wrong to me. "An was denkst Du?" would be ok.

Comment: @Beta "Was denkst du?" would have another meaning. You're rather asking to a opinion on sth. "What do you think of it?".